# How to identify Property Custom Type in Listener?

Tags: c#, encryption, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We use a custom type (*IUserType*) in some properties mapping to encrypt the data in the database, and we use listeners (*IPostUpdateEventListener, IPostDeleteEventListener, IPostInsertEventListener*) to log changes in some entities, its all base in entity Attributes to decide if log is necessary or not. The problem is encrypted properties are logged without encryption.

Is there a way, with the *IEntityPersister* or other source, to identify witch property is encrypted (uses our custom type) or not?

```
    private string GetValue(ISession session, object[] stateArray, int index, IEntityPersister persister)
    {
        try
        {
            return stateArray[index] == null || stateArray[index].ToString() == string.Empty
                ? "< No value >"
                : stateArray[index].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.Write(string.Format("Error \"{0}[{1}]\": {2}", persister.EntityName, persister.PropertyTypes[index],
                e));
            return "< No value >";
        }
    }
...
    public void OnPostInsert(PostInsertEvent @event)
    {
        var res = GetValue(session, @event.State, i, @event.Persister);
...
```

Comment: You should use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(stateArray[index])`

Comment: it is an array of objects

Comment: True! Sorry for that :/

Comment: `Persistor.PropertyTypes[i] is CustomType` and `CustomType.UserType` to get which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378978/how-to-identify-property-custom-type-in-listener?noredirect=1#comment53021284_32378978) solution worked:

```
...
if (Persistor.PropertyTypes[i] is CustomType && (Persistor.PropertyTypes[i] as CustomType).UserType is MyUserType)
    return "Encrypted";
...
```